# Transforming wcf endpoint issues

Tags: .net, wcf

I am having a number of issues with profilers and web.config transformations can anyone point out what I am doing wrong

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="saservices" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint name="saservices" address="http://xxxxxx/Service/Service.svc" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your missing the `xdt:Transform="SetAttributes"` Add this in the `<endpoint>` tag and there is no reason why this shouldn't then work.

message back if this isn't the fix and ill try to help you

Thanks Alan

Comment: Thanks @alanMorton2.0, this has done the trick... Just couldn't see it myself thanks again.